# Exporting from overleaf

Tags: overleaf

I already achieved 60 files in Overleaf inside my project which is the limit. Can I export and work on another platform online or ofline, without sunbscribing to paid overleaf? Also, I am not sure if I will hve unlimited nr of files if subscribing. It isnt put in the paid plan of overleaf.

Thanks,

Comment: This question is specific to Overleaf. I would suggest you ask the support of Overleaf on this regard. Of course, you should be free to download your files, store them on your computer locally and re-upload them to Overleaf once you need to do so.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

*(Disclaimer: I'm a support personnel at Overleaf. If this question/answer is inappropariate for TeX.SX, could an administrator delete this and direct similar questions to contact support@overleaf.com?)*

Overleaf v1 does have a 60 files limit on Free plans, but Overleaf v2's limit is 2000 files: https://www.overleaf.com/learn/Uploading_a_project#Limitations_on_Uploads

Therefore you can port your project over to Overleaf V2 by clicking on the project's name in your V2 Dashboard.

<s>If you would like to continue using Overleaf V1 with this project for now, you can contact support@overleaf.com with your project's URL for the file number quota to be increased.</s>

If you'd like to download your V1 project, you can click on the "Download as .zip" button at the bottom of the file list panel. You can also [git-clone](https://www.overleaf.com/blog/195-new-collaborate-online-and-offline-with-overleaf-and-git-beta) the project if you prefer.

Overleaf v1 has been retired on 8 January 2019. You can still export or download your project files, by clicking on the Overleaf menu icon above the file list panel in the v2 editor, and then on "Download > Source".

Comment: Hello, Actually I tried every possible way to shrink my files, but I have a lot of images and things. Anyway, yes, my project is in V1, and I just subscribed to the paid version. I undestand that you also need some support for your work.

Comment: Thank you very much for the update, LianTze!! :)

Answer (score 0):

Since sharelatex and overleaf joined forces I think you are out of luck and other if you could port your project I don't think it would be as good.

Do you mind sharing your project structure? Do you have a lot of images and/or files? There are ways to reduce the hacky number of files such as making all your images into a pdf and then including them one by one, etc ...

You could always install latex manually, there are editors for every platform.

See https://www.sharelatex.com/blog/2017/07/20/sharelatex-joins-overleaf.html

Comment: I edited and reduced as many files as possible. But I do not understand your way of putting all the images in one pdf???? And I have  atemplate in overleaf, thats why I was asking, how to export a template in other platforms

Comment: you can just download the entire folder as a zip, as for other platforms, there really aren't many alternatives. And/or having a single pdf that contains all figures http://em7e.eecs.umich.edu/pdf/ulaby_figures_tables.pdf, and reference each page using either pdfpages and/or possibly graphicx.

Honestly, there aren't many alternatives to overleaf.

Comment: Ok, thank  you  even tough Im not sure if I want a pdf with images