# How to change new document initial contents on Overleaf

Tags: overleaf

When you create a new 'main' document on Overleaf, it appears with some basic info filled in: document class, begin document, etc. . Is it possible to change what it automatically puts in this? Also, when you create a second document in that project, it is blank. Is there any way to add initial info to the subsequent documents within a project? It would be especially helpful if I could change the initial info depending on the project. I am aware of document templates but as far as I know they don't satisfy my purpose completely.

Comment: This is an Overleaf-only question, so you should ask this to the Overleaf support.

Comment: I get that, but I checked out the other questions tagged Overleaf, and they are mostly Overleaf only. See https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/461759/exporting-from-overleaf, https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/512998/vim-latex-on-overleaf, https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/469787/overleaf-v2-saving-versions I feel it could be helpful to other people using Latex since many use Overleaf.

Comment: You are correct, all those questions (perhaps the vim-latex one to some lesser extent) are off-topic here. As you can see, the “exporting from Overleaf” one was answered by a staff member, with details on limits of free accounts. Drawing the line between on/off topic is very subjective, so you might want to try to rephrase your question to sound a bit less Overleaf-y (it can be reopened), or ask a new one. Although I think (and I might be wrong, of course) that their support team will provide you with a better answer. Sorry for the inconvenience.